# I was trying Build For Archiving application with xCode 4.4, but I get this error

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, titanium, archiving

I was trying Build For Archiving application (from Titanium Mobile) with xCode 4.4, but I get this error:

```
    Validate "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sweet_Dream-gmqsujzdxwsgxtdhddwaatzuspsq/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Sweet Dream.app"
    cd "/Users/admin/Desktop/TitaniumWorkspace2/Sweet Dream/build/iphone"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sweet_Dream-gmqsujzdxwsgxtdhddwaatzuspsq/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Sweet Dream.app"

warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: appicon.png: icon dimensions (512 x 512) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation failed with exit code 1
```

Any help much appreciated.

Grant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application icon was not set in your xcode it was stating that appicon.png was with dimension 515x515 but it should be 57x57. So change the application icon in the build setting of your project